# Rails 3.1: how to run an initializer only for the web app (rails server/unicorn/etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, initializer, rake-task

My webapp needs to encrypt its session data. What I setup is:

```rb
config/initializers/encryptor.rb:

require 'openssl'
require 'myapp/encryptor'

MyApp::Encryptor.config[ :random_key ] = OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes( 128 )
Session.delete_all

app/models/session.rb:

require 'attr_encrypted'

class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :session_id, :data
  attr_encryptor :data, :key => proc { MyApp::Encryptor.config[ :random_key ] }, :marshal => true

  # Rest of model stuff
end
```

That all works great, and keeps the session data secured. Here's the problem: when I run my custom rake tasks it loads the initializer and clears all the sessions. Not good!

What can I put in my initializer to make sure it ONLY runs for the webapp initialization? Or, what can I put in my initializer to make it NOT run for rake tasks?

**Update:** OK, what I've done for the moment is add `MYAPP_IN_RAKE = true unless defined? MYAPP_IN_RAKE` to my .rake file. And then in my initializer I do:

```
unless defined?( MYAPP_IN_RAKE ) && MYAPP_IN_RAKE
    # Web only initialization
end
```

Seems to work. But I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: This seems liable to bite you in other ways in the future. Any time the server is restarted, you're going to lose all your sessions (which seems to be the intended behavior), but that includes the server getting autokilled by using too much memory, having a request run too long, etc.

Comment: I understand the downsides, but I think it is worth it. App being restarted resetting sessions: acceptable. Too much memory or too long of a request? Under unicorn these situations should only happen in a worker process. And since I set `preload_app = true` the initialization only happens in the master. So unicorn can respawn workers without causing a re-initialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3 initializers that run only on \`rails server\` and not \`rails generate\`, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660019/rails-3-initializers-that-run-only-on-rails-server-and-not-rails-generate-e)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might make a modification to your application in `config/application.rb' like this:

```
module MyApp
  def self.rake?
    !!@rake
  end

  def self.rake=(value)
    @rake = !!value
  end
```

Then in your `Rakefile` you'd add this:

```
MyApp.rake = true
```

It's nice to use methods rather than constants since sometimes you'd prefer to change or redefine them later. Plus, they don't pollute the root namespace.

Here's a sample `config/initializers/rake_environment_test.rb` script:

```
if (MyApp.rake?)
  puts "In rake"
else
  puts "Not in rake"
end
```

The programmable nature of the `Rakefile` affords you significant flexibility.

Comment: OK, I like this. I've changed the setter to `@rake = !!value unless defined? @rake` to make sure it's only set once. Then I also added to environment.rb `MyApp.rake = false`. Sound reasonable?

Comment: Why would you worry about setting it only once? A better practice than simply ignoring the duplicate set is to at least emit a warning, or better, to throw an exception so you can track down the source of the problem.

Comment: I guess I'm concerned that while running as webapp code somehow the Rakefile will get loaded. I'm thinking symmetrically: as rake, the webapp environment is loaded, so I should also handle the case where as the webapp, rake gets loaded.

Comment: If you load your `Rakefile` from inside your app, you are doing something *very* peculiar. I don't think that even works.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for this. It feels a little hacky, is this the only way to achieve this?

Comment: If by "hacky" you mean "not a standard use case" then yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

There is another work around:

```
unless ENV["RAILS_ENV"].nil? || ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == 'test'
```

When you launch with rake your ENV["RAILS_ENV"] will be nil. The test for 'test' is to avoid to run when using rspec.

I know that is reckon to use Rails.env but it return "development" when it is not initialised.

http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/env/class

```
# File railties/lib/rails.rb, line 55
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] 
     || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just what I needed!