# How to prevent initializers from running when running `rails generate`

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, initialization

I want to prepopulate my cache with an initializer, but I don't need this code to run every time I run `rake` or `rails g`, etc.  Rake and Bundler are easy to deal with, but a similar solution does not work for the generators:

```
# config/initializers/prepop_cache.rb
if !defined?(::Bundler) and !defined?(::Rake) and !defined(Rails::Generators)
  # do stuff
end
```

This must be because `rails/generators` (or something similar) is `require`ed at runtime.  How can I check to see if the command being run is `rails g xyz`?

Update:

Two solutions can be found here:  [Rails 3 initializers that run only on `rails server` and not `rails generate`, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660019/rails-3-initializers-that-run-only-on-rails-server-and-not-rails-generate-e)

Still would like to know if it's possible in the manner I've tried above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Rails 3**, what you're looking to do is conceivably possible, but in a hacky way. Here's how:

When you make a `rails generate` call, the callpath looks like this:

- [bin/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/bin/rails) is called, which eventually routes you to [execute script/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb#L8-L19)
- [script/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/script/rails) is executed which requires [rails/commands](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/script/rails#L5)
- [rails/commands](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb) is loaded, which is the main point of focus.

Within [rails/commands](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb) the code that runs for generate:

```
ARGV << '--help' if ARGV.empty?

aliases = {
  "g"  => "generate",
  "c"  => "console",
  "s"  => "server",
  "db" => "dbconsole"
}

command = ARGV.shift                       # <= #1
command = aliases[command] || command

case command
when 'generate', 'destroy', 'plugin', 'benchmarker', 'profiler'
  require APP_PATH
  Rails.application.require_environment!   # <= #2
  require "rails/commands/#{command}"      # <= #3
```

The points of interest are numbered above. Namely, that at point `#1` the command that you're running is shifting off of `ARGV`. Which in your case means `generate` is going to be removed from the command line args.

At point `#2` your environment gets loaded, at which point your initializers are going to be executed. And herein is the tough part - because nothing indicating a specific command has been loaded at this point (this occurs at `#3`) there is no information to determine a generator is being run!

Let's insert a script into `config/initializer/debug.rb` to see what is available if we ran `rails generate model meep`:

```
puts $0     #=> "script/rails"
puts ARGV   #=> ["model", "meep"]
```

As you can see, there is no direct information that a generator is being run. That said, there is indirect information. Namely `ARGV[0] #=> "model"`. Conceivably you could create a list of possible generators and check to see if that generator has been called on `ARGV[0]`. The responsible developer in me says this is a hack and may break in ways you'd not expect so I'd use this cautiously.

The only other option is to modify `script/rails` like you suggested -- which isn't too bad a solution, but would likely break when you upgrade to Rails 4.

---

In **Rails 4**, you've got more hope! By the time the [application environment is being loaded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb#L133), the generators namespace has already been loaded. This means that in an initializer you could do the following:

```
if defined? Rails::Generators   #=> "constant"
  # code to run if generators loaded
else
  # code to run if generators not loaded
end
```