# How to distinguish between Rails and Rake at the initializers level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, rake

Whether I execute rails or rake, the code present in the initializers folder will be executed. What I want to do is to make sure that the code in a given initializer file doesn't get fired up when running a rake task (hence only when Rails server or console are launched).

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like (in `config/initializers/blabla.rb`):

```
do_something # code always executed
unless ENV['rake']
  something_when_not_rake # code executed only if rails server or console
end
do_something_more # more code always executed
```

I've been looking into the `ENV` variable to see what's available there but I've seen nothing interesting, here's the content (in the format `"key" => "value"`):

```
"rvm_bin_path" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/bin"
"GEM_HOME" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3"
"SHELL" => "/bin/bash"
"TERM" => "xterm-256color"
"TMPDIR" => "/var/folders/73/q8t0jjrx3zb8zvd072dgq11c0000gn/T/"
"IRBRC" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/.irbrc"
"Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render" => "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.mF5Uh4NPbk/Render"
"MY_RUBY_HOME" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3"
"USER" => "lucke84"
"rvm_stored_umask" => "0022"
"_system_type" => "Darwin"
"rvm_path" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm"
"SSH_AUTH_SOCK" => "/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ryhqrdVtVU/Listeners"
"__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING" => "0x1F5:0x0:0x0"
"rvm_prefix" => "/Users/lucke84"
"PATH" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:/Users/lucke84/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:/Users/lucke84/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin"
"rvm_loaded_flag" => "1"
"PWD" => "/Users/lucke84/projects/website"
"JAVA_HOME" => "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home"
"XPC_FLAGS" => "0x0"
"_system_arch" => "x86_64"
"_system_version" => "10.11"
"XPC_SERVICE_NAME" => "0"
"rvm_version" => "1.26.11 (latest)"
"HOME" => "/Users/lucke84"
"SHLVL" => "1"
"rvm_ruby_string" => "ruby-2.2.3"
"LOGNAME" => "lucke84"
"LC_CTYPE" => "en_US.UTF-8"
"GEM_PATH" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global"
"rvm_delete_flag" => "0"
"RUBY_VERSION" => "ruby-2.2.3"
"_system_name" => "OSX"
"rvm_user_install_flag" => "1"
"BUNDLE_GEMFILE" => "/Users/lucke84/projects/website/Gemfile"
"_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3:/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global"
"BUNDLE_BIN_PATH" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/bin/bundle"
"RUBYOPT" => "-rbundler/setup"
"RUBYLIB" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib"
"MANPATH" => "/Users/lucke84/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/man"
```

I cannot find a built-in environment key/value to programmatically determine who is triggering the command. Maybe one of you can shed some light on this topic for me?

Further details:

- this cannot be an environment-dependent check, it should work for development as well as for production (or whatever the environment)
- I would like to avoid to specify a custom parameter (i.e. `bin/rake my:task skip_initializer=true`), as what I'm trying to do is to skip that initializer's executions for all rake tasks
- running Rails 4.2.x at the moment

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7508170/438992

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton! I was hoping in a built-in solution I couldn't find, but this would do it :)